# SMS can not send by SDK without any exception (it works with AWS Web Console)

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, amazon-sns

I'm using the AWS to send SMS via my app.

I can send SMS via AWS web console, however, sending SMS via SDK is not successfull, without any exception information, the status of sending request is 200 and still receiving the returned value of AWS_REQUEST_ID.

```
AmazonSNSClient snsClient = new AmazonSNSClient(new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey));
Map<String, MessageAttributeValue> smsAttributes = new HashMap<String, MessageAttributeValue>();

smsAttributes.put("AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID", new MessageAttributeValue()
                .withStringValue("mySenderID") //The sender ID shown on the device.
                .withDataType("String"));
smsAttributes.put("AWS.SNS.SMS.MaxPrice", new MessageAttributeValue()
                .withStringValue("1") //Sets the max price to 0.50 USD.
                .withDataType("Number"));

// Sets the type to promotional
smsAttributes.put("AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType",
                new MessageAttributeValue().withStringValue("Promotional").withDataType("String"));

JSONObject smsService = (JSONObject) new JSONObject(json).get("smsService");
        String phoneNumber = smsService.getString("phoneNumber");
        String message = smsService.getString("message");
```

`PublishResult result = snsClient.publish(new PublishRequest().withMessage(message).withPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                .withMessageAttributes(smsAttributes));
LOGGER.info("Message ID: {}", result); // Prints the message ID.`

Answer (score 0):

After for a while of researching, I detect that the root cause is the budget is over, so I can not send SMS anymore (I track the log to detect it).